# Not seeing Terminal colors properly in OSX

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm a new OSX (10.9) user, and I wanted to setup the Terminal with a decent color scheme, but I'm not able to.
I followed simple instructions here:

http://noahfrederick.com/blog/2011/lion-terminal-theme-peppermint/

Imported the file, applied the theme, but it looks like this:

[image]

What could be going on here? I've tried the same with numerous other themes, but my terminal just doesn't seem to take the colors.

Answer (score 0):

Terminal > Preferences - Settings (Gear)>  Import select Peppermint Terminal

Select the Peppermint Profile

Also note the bit about getting color in bash in the comments:

.bashrc file:

COLOR_BOLD="[\e[1m]"
COLOR_DEFAULT="[\e[0m]"
PS1="$COLOR_BOLD\u@\h \w \$ $COLOR_DEFAULT"

# Likewise, colored output from various utilities including ls can be turned on with

export CLICOLOR=1

You can try an existing color Profile to determine whether or not you should be seeing color. In the case of no color being enabled I'd suggest some googling.